# В WPF регистр букв автоматически менялся при вводе

Tags: c#, wpf

В textBox нужно сделать так чтобы при вводе первая буква автоматически была большой. То есть я пишу фамилию с маленькой, а программа сама исправляет на большую. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Comment: А это не вы задавали практически такой же вопрос вчера?

Answer (score 1):

Если лень подключать `xpression.Blend.Sdk` то вот простое но довольно корявое решение:

Разметка

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="155,102,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Обработчик `TextChanged`

```
public int i = 0;
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text[0].ToString().ToUpper();
    }
    else
    {
        textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
    }
    if (textBox.Text.Length ==0)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

При вводе текста считаем i равно 1 и первый символ выводим в верхнем ключе, далее переводим каретку в конец текстового поля и выводим текст как он есть в обычном реестре. При удалении всего содержимого текстполя обнуляем i и сного вводим с большой буквы. Хотя конечно для каждого поля придется заводить отдельную переменную для хранения числа символов что не есть гуд.